# How are cellphone IP addresses assigned?

Tags: internet, nat, ip-address, mobile-devices

When my cellphone accesses a website via the tower and its GPRS gateway, NAT ensures that the sites receive a public IP. Would all phones using a single tower have the same IP?

- If **yes**, then how can the mass of received HTTP data routed to the correct cellphone? And how can websites differentiate between cellphone visitors? Is there additional HTTP header data?
- If **no**, then how are these unique IPs assigned? Based on availability or location? Would each tower have a fixed set of IPs?

Comment: If you happen to have an Android phone, you can check your local IP in settings -> status, it's most likely 10.x.y.z. Then visit http://www.whatsmyip.org to see your public IP. Then compare it with a friend's phone who has the same provider.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To answer your first question mobile/cell-phone IP addresses are handed out using DHCP like any other client device. To answer your second questions, well yes, through NAT - that's what NAT does, it allows multiple 'inside' devices to get IP services through a NAT gateway - external IP services will not be able to identify individual internal devices like phones by IP but could via a session ID, cookie or similar.

Comment: I'm a little confused, would all phones using a tower have the same public IP address? yes/no?

Comment: Provider dependent. There's no reason they have to though.

Comment: I thought most cell phones use PPP, and so they don't actually use DHCP but instead get their IP from the remote end of the ppp connection...

Comment: You're right, at least for all the providers in ie.

Comment: Correct, the traffic only turns into IP in a one or only a few centralised locations - it isn't IP traffic at the tower.

Comment: Remember also why: Phones must be able to switch towers. DHCP per tower would mean new IP address which would break all connections currently open.